# How to use Authorization in Postman collections?

Tags: postman

I have URL for get user details (GET method) while running the URL its showing the response below.

```
{
    "message": "Invalid Basic Auth credentials"
}
```

URL details below

```
http://localhost:4567/v1/candidates
```

they mentioned following for authorization

```
-H "Authorization: Basic *********************************"
```

How can I use this in Postman collection?

Answer (score 0):

Go to postman `Authorization` Tab and select `Basic Auth` as type and type the required credentials `(username and password)`

Comment: I am not have username and password.

Comment: Then you can't authenticate :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `Basic xxxxxxxxx` to the Authorization header in your call:

[image: Authorization header in postman]